# C++/CLI with C# WPF passing HWND and HINSTANCE

Tags: c#, wpf, c++-cli

How can I pass the HWND and HINSTANCE of a C# WPF Form?

Attempt:

C++/CLI:

```
BOOL Initialize(double width, double height, HWND parent, HINSTANCE hiparent)
{
```

C#

```
HwndSource hwnd = (HwndSource)HwndSource.FromVisual(this.renderControl);
IntPtr hinstance = Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(typeof(App).Module);

engine.Initialize(this.Width, this.Height, hwnd, hinstance);
```

But throws:

> Argument 4: cannot convert from 'System.IntPtr' to 'HINSTANCE__*'
>   Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource' to
>   'HWND__*'

So how can I convert these into those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider trying this:

```
engine.Initialize(this.Width, this.Height, hwnd.Handle.ToPointer(), hinstance.ToPointer());
```

`IntPtr.ToPointer()` returns a `void*` which should be convertible to `HWND` and `HINSTANCE`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
engine.Initialize(this.Width, this.Height, (HWND)(hwnd.Handle.ToPointer()), (HINSTANCE)hinstance.ToPointer());
```